# STM32F303x6 Center-Aligned PWM ADC timing HAL

Tags: stm32

I want to implement the Center-Aligned PWM and set the ADC trigger according to figure 42. I can only use Timer 2 to achieve this, since the Center-Aligned PWM is done with Timer 2, but I don't know if this even is possible? From the second figure I posted you see there are only two trigger possibilities, "Capture compare 2 event" and "Trigger out event", which one should I choose?

[image: Figure 42]

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Actually what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know if timer 2 is able to trigger the ADC1 in the way as shown in figure 1.

Comment: it is. You need to set the proper event in the MMS field of the CR2 TIM2 register. How to archive it in HAL I do not know as I do not use it. Bare registers approach gives you full control over the hardware without guessing what to put into those strange HAL structures

Comment: I have now set hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv=ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T2_CC2, such that it should be triggered by timer 2, but I don't know what event this actually is, also in the RM0316 I cannot find a definition for it. How can I set know the timer 2 to trigger the ADC in the right moment?

Comment: aas I told you - try the bare regsters. you need to set the MMS bits and EXTSEL and EXTEN in the ADC CTRL register. 3 lines of code using registers - 50+ lines with HAL + 3 weeks of problems :)